# AForge.Net Filters alternatives for Monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

Is there any options? I can't get it worked for Monotouch. Seems like some functions missing from AForge*.dll's.
Now, I'm looking at OpenCV, but it's just too complicated for such a simple problem. But still very interesting :)

Well, there is no problem with `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, I've built it from [github.com/mono/](http://github.com/mono/) and it worked. But there is errors related to AForge framework. When I try to apply filter through `Bitmap Apply (Bitmap image)` from `AForge.Imaging.Filters.BaseFilter` I'm getting the error:

> Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Method not found: 'AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage.CollectActivePixels'. (CS0584) (projectName)

Also, when I'm trying to use `AForge.Imaging.Filters.Sepia` or `Invert`, compiler couldn't find them:

> Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `AForge.Imaging.Filters.Sepia' from` AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b' (CS0584) (projectName)

The interesting thing is that `AForge.Imaging.Filters.Grayscale` found.

Here is the code that produces these errors:

This one produces "**Could not import type**" errors:

```
partial void showFilters (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        UIActionSheet sheet = new UIActionSheet ("Filters");
        // @TODO: I'll hardcode filters for now, but in future it should be refactored out.
        sheet.AddButton ("Grayscale");
        sheet.AddButton ("Sepia");
        sheet.AddButton ("Invert");
        sheet.Clicked += 
            (sndr, e) => {
            var ev = (UIButtonEventArgs)e;
            switch (ev.ButtonIndex) {
            case 0:
                imageView.Image = ImageProcessor.process (imageView.Image, new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721));
                break;
            case 1:
                imageView.Image = ImageProcessor.process (imageView.Image, new Sepia());
                break;
            case 2:
                imageView.Image = ImageProcessor.process (imageView.Image, new Invert());
                break;
            }
            imageView.Image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) => {
                var o = image as UIImage;
                Console.WriteLine("error:" + error);
            });
        };
        sheet.ShowInView (this.View);
    }
```

First 3 functions produces "**Method not found: 'AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage.CollectActivePixels'.**:

```
    #region methods
    static public Bitmap process (String fileName, IFilter filter)
    {
        if (File.Exists (fileName)) {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile (fileName);
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) filter.Apply (bitmap);
            return image;
        } else {
            throw (new FileNotFoundException());
        }
    }

    static public Bitmap process (String fileName, FiltersSequence seq)
    {
        if (File.Exists (fileName)) {
            Bitmap image = Bitmap.FromFile (fileName);
            image = seq.Apply (image);
            return image;
        } else {
            throw (new FileNotFoundException());
        }
    }
    #region iOS
    static public UIImage process (UIImage capturedImage, IFilter filter)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromUIImage (capturedImage);
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) filter.Apply (bitmap);
        UIImage result = getUIImageFromBitmap (image);
        return result;
    }

    static public Bitmap getBitmapFromUIImage (UIImage capturedImage)
    {
        NSData imageData = capturedImage.AsPNG();
        Byte[] byteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy (imageData.Bytes,
                                                     byteArray,
                                                     0,
                                                     Convert.ToInt32 (imageData.Length));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream (byteArray);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap (stream, false);
        return bitmap;
    }

    static public UIImage getUIImageFromBitmap (Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Byte[] byteArray;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(stream);
        stream.Close();
        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        NSData imageData = NSData.FromArray(byteArray);
        return UIImage.LoadFromData(imageData);
    }
    #endregion iOS
    #endregion methods

}
```

And the complete list of errors:

```
Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `AForge.Imaging.Filters.Sepia' from `AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b' (CS0584) (tryingImageProcessing)
Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `AForge.Imaging.Filters.Invert' from `AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b' (CS0584) (tryingImageProcessing)
Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Method not found: 'AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage.CollectActivePixels'. (CS0584) (tryingImageProcessing)
Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `object' to `System.Drawing.Bitmap'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266) (tryingImageProcessing)
```

I didn't say anything about the last error because it's easy to repair, but I can't understand why it's showing up. It cries about:

```
Bitmap image = ((BaseFilter) filter).Apply (bitmap);
```

And every line where I use `Apply`.

[This is the project itself (Monodevelop, zipped).](http://dump.bitcheese.net/files/awitaje/ImageProcessing.zip/preview)

**Answer:** [Monodevelop. Method that visible from Assembly Browser not found. (CS0584)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983272/monodevelop-method-that-visible-from-assembly-browser-not-found-cs0584)

Comment: Did you try to build from source as a new MonoTouch library project?  You won't be able to use dlls compiled on Windows in MonoTouch.  If it  doesn't compile, post the code and the error it gives.  There may be a workaround.

Comment: Jonathan.Peppers, one of the problem is that class "System.Drawing.Bitmap" (fundamental class for AForge library) is not available under target framework "Mono for iPhone". It is only available under target framework "Mono / .NET <X.Y>".

Comment: There is a `System.Drawing` port on GitHub here: https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics It is a wrapper around CoreGraphics to enable people to reuse GDI+ code.  It does not have every single feature, but most of them.

Comment: Finally, the problem is in sysdrawing-coregraphics. It doesn't have needed functionality.