# Monodevelop. Method that visible from Assembly Browser not found. (CS0584)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

I have the .dll that is part of AForge.NET framework. I can't compile project because:

```
Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `AForge.Imaging.Filters.Sepia' from `AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b' (CS0584) (projectName)
Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `AForge.Imaging.Filters.Invert' from `AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b' (CS0584) (projectName)
Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Method not found: 'AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage.CollectActivePixels'. (CS0584) (tryingImageProcessing)
```

But all of these methods and classes are visible from the assembly browser.
[Here is the link](http://dump.bitcheese.net/files/awitaje/ImageProcessing.zip/preview) to the project with error. I also [reported a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6543) to xamarin bugzilla.

*Hope this post wouldn't be treated as copy of my previous: question of that post is completely different from current.*

**UPDATE:** 
Well, I've found what the problem was. @Jason was right: I haven't compiled libraries against MonoTouch, it was compiled against Mono. So I've created new projects and past sources there. AForge (Core) and AForge.Math compiled perfectly while AForge.Imaging hasn't: System.Drawing from github.com/mono/ implement some functions that AForge.Imaging needs. Hence, there is no solution by now.

Comment: Are you simply trying to use the existing AForge.NET dll in a MT project?  That won't work - you need to compile their source using MT, or have a version of the dll that has already been compiled against MT.

Comment: No, I've downloaded sources from http://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/checkout then I've compiled AForge.dll from sources (Core) using "for mono" .sln in Monodevelop, then AForge.Math the same way and AForge.Imaging finally. Then I've added these dlls to References in my project. I just can't understand how could it be: even code of every function is visible in assembly browser, but linker can't see it.

Comment: Compiling against Mono won't do it. You need to compile the code against **MonoTouch** supplied assemblies. Otherwise you will find yourself with references to assemblies, types, methods... that might not be available inside MonoTouch.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already found myself in that situation ._. Now I'm trying to add missing structures and functions to System.Drawing from github.com/mono

Comment: Did you try using System.Drawing from here: https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics

Comment: Yeah, I've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960841/aforge-net-filters-alternatives-for-monotouch. Now I'm going to fork this repo and start developing on my own. Because almost nothing implemented in there.